# Single Image Gallery Post

Tags: gallery

I'm trying to edit my new theme and I got the [following comments](http://themes.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/7786#comment:2):

1. Single image gallery post: image shifted in left side with footer
2. Need next and previous image gallery link on single image gallery post.

I know how to create a gallery post with many thumbnails, but how do I create a single gallery post in order to simulate the above to comments?

Comment: I really don't understand your question and it may be marked as "too localized". Please, take a look at the [FAQ](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq) and try to improve it.

Comment: For future reference, please post review-specific question **in your Theme review ticket**, so that your questions can be answered more quickly/effectively. As-is, this question borders on *too localized* (it is specific to your Theme Review ticket) and/or *not a real question* (it is easily answered with a mere Codex link) for WPSE.

Comment: Thanks Chip! Yes, as a first timer, I just figured that you can comment in your review ticket and ask your reviewer directly. Will do so from now on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read [Theme Unit Test](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Unit_Test) and import the test data (including images!) into a new blog. You will get everything you need to test.

There is a gallery post included (*Images Test*), and if you click on an image you get an attachment page for this gallery image.

Here is a screen shot from TwentyEleven:

[image]

See the links in the upper right corner? Look into the source code of TwentyEleven to understand how they are implemented.
Use [`previous_image_link()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_image_link) and [`next_image_link()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_image_link).

```
<span class="nav-previous"><?php 
    previous_image_link( false, __( '&larr; Previous' , 'twentyeleven' ) ); 
?></span>
<span class="nav-next"><?php 
    next_image_link( false, __( 'Next &rarr;' , 'twentyeleven' ) ); 
?></span>
```